# How to run a for loop through a list in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe that contains lists within each cell of column of a dataframe. For example's sake, here is a test dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:2)
df$month <-  list(c("1","2","3"), c("3","5","7"))
df
```

I want to compute the mean differences within each list in a row and store the results as a new variable, let's say MeanDiff. E.g. (1,2,3) has mean difference of 1 (((2-1)+(3-2))/2).

My outside for loop would be

```
for (i in 1: nrow(df)){
}
```

However, I don't know how to loop across each element of the list in the row that I have to run a function on, which would look something like

```
Diff = []
Diff[i] = i+1 - i
MeanDiff[i] = Diff/length(Diff)
```

Any help would be appreciated! Also, this being my first StackOverflow post, I'd also appreciate any meta-feedback on question-asking!

Comment: Do you intentionally complicate it by needing to calculate differences of `character` strings? I recognize this is just an example.

Comment: It's because when I aggregated the data, the way I did it returned strings 
    summarize(Month = paste(Month, collapse = ",") from dplyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions:

```
df$diff <- lapply(df$month, function(a) sum(diff(as.numeric(a)))/2)
df
#   id   month diff
# 1  1 1, 2, 3    1
# 2  2 3, 5, 7    2
```

One catch with this is that though it looks like a regular column, it is not exactly what you might expect:

```
df$diff[1]
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
```

That is a `list` of a single element, where you might expect a scalar (or vector of length 1, in R's case). An alternative (as JilberUrbina suggested) is to use `sapply` in cases where you expect the result to be length 1:

```
df$diff2 <- sapply(df$month, function(a) sum(diff(as.numeric(a)))/2)
df$diff2[1]
# [1] 1
```

If you are otherwise using the [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/) set of tools (which many recommend), try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    diff = map(month, ~ sum(diff(as.numeric(.)))/2)
  )
#   id   month diff
# 1  1 1, 2, 3    1
# 2  2 3, 5, 7    2
```

If you store it in the `tidyverse`'s default of a `tibble`, it'll appear like this:

```
tbl_df(df) %>%
  mutate(
    diff = map(month, ~ sum(diff(as.numeric(.)))/2)
  )
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#      id month     diff     
#   <int> <list>    <list>   
# 1     1 <chr [3]> <dbl [1]>
# 2     2 <chr [3]> <dbl [1]>
```

though it is effectively the same thing. If you're planning on repeatedly storing lists or other complex things within a column (e.g., `lm` model, `predict`ions), then this can be very convenient and perhaps eventually intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply`

```
> lapply(df$month, function(x) 
    {tmp <- as.numeric(x)  # this converts character to numeric
    tmp <- sum(diff(tmp))/(length(tmp)-1) # performs calculations
    tmp})  # returns output
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

Or `sapply` if you want the output to be a vector instead of a list.